# Unable to join new node to existing cluster: [discovery] Failed to request cluster info, will try again: [Unauthorized]

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, kube-apiserver

I have an existing kubernetes 1.11.3 cluster and I'm unable to join new nodes to it.

I'm attempting to join by creating a new token with the --print-join-command flag through kubeadm on the master

Then I run that join command as sudo on the new worker node - but get the following output:

```
[discovery] Trying to connect to API Server "x.x.x.x:6443"
[discovery] Created cluster-info discovery client, requesting info from "https://x.x.x.x:6443"
[discovery] Failed to request cluster info, will try again: [Unauthorized]
[discovery] Failed to request cluster info, will try again: [Unauthorized]
```

My understanding is that this output is caused by the --anonymous-auth flag on the api-server being set to false.  But mine is explicitly set to true.

I'm unable to find any logs to give me more information about what api-server or controller manager are doing with the join request.  Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place?  Has anyone seen this before?

As requested - the output from kubeadm -v9 join (with the ip masked).

```
I0304 09:13:14.427364 3176882 join.go:226] [join] found NodeName empty
I0304 09:13:14.427443 3176882 join.go:227] [join] considered OS hostname as NodeName
[preflight] running pre-flight checks
I0304 09:13:14.427578 3176882 join.go:238] [preflight] running various checks on all nodes
I0304 09:13:14.427630 3176882 checks.go:253] validating the existence and emptiness of directory /etc/kubernetes/manifests
I0304 09:13:14.427699 3176882 checks.go:291] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
I0304 09:13:14.427717 3176882 checks.go:291] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
I0304 09:13:14.427732 3176882 checks.go:291] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf
I0304 09:13:14.427753 3176882 kernelcheck_linux.go:45] validating the kernel module IPVS required exists in machine or not
    [WARNING RequiredIPVSKernelModulesAvailable]: the IPVS proxier will not be used, because the following required kernel modules are not loaded: [ip_vs ip_vs_rr ip_vs_wrr ip_vs_sh] or no builtin kernel ipvs support: map[ip_vs:{} ip_vs_rr:{} ip_vs_wrr:{} ip_vs_sh:{} nf_conntrack_ipv4:{}]
you can solve this problem with following methods:
 1. Run 'modprobe -- ' to load missing kernel modules;
2. Provide the missing builtin kernel ipvs support

I0304 09:13:14.431606 3176882 checks.go:138] validating if the service is enabled and active
I0304 09:13:14.448891 3176882 checks.go:340] validating the contents of file /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
I0304 09:13:14.448970 3176882 checks.go:340] validating the contents of file /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
I0304 09:13:14.449017 3176882 checks.go:653] validating whether swap is enabled or not
I0304 09:13:14.449083 3176882 checks.go:381] validating the presence of executable crictl
I0304 09:13:14.449131 3176882 checks.go:381] validating the presence of executable ip
I0304 09:13:14.449165 3176882 checks.go:381] validating the presence of executable iptables
I0304 09:13:14.449195 3176882 checks.go:381] validating the presence of executable mount
I0304 09:13:14.449224 3176882 checks.go:381] validating the presence of executable nsenter
I0304 09:13:14.449252 3176882 checks.go:381] validating the presence of executable ebtables
I0304 09:13:14.449281 3176882 checks.go:381] validating the presence of executable ethtool
I0304 09:13:14.449307 3176882 checks.go:381] validating the presence of executable socat
I0304 09:13:14.449346 3176882 checks.go:381] validating the presence of executable tc
I0304 09:13:14.449377 3176882 checks.go:381] validating the presence of executable touch
I0304 09:13:14.449402 3176882 checks.go:523] running all checks
I0304 09:13:14.451248 3176882 kernel_validator.go:81] Validating kernel version
I0304 09:13:14.451372 3176882 kernel_validator.go:96] Validating kernel config
I0304 09:13:14.780475 3176882 checks.go:411] checking whether the given node name is reachable using net.LookupHost
I0304 09:13:14.780711 3176882 checks.go:622] validating kubelet version
I0304 09:13:14.951219 3176882 checks.go:138] validating if the service is enabled and active
I0304 09:13:14.966615 3176882 checks.go:216] validating availability of port 10250
I0304 09:13:14.966764 3176882 checks.go:438] validating if the connectivity type is via proxy or direct
I0304 09:13:14.966809 3176882 join.go:251] [join] retrieving KubeConfig objects
[discovery] Trying to connect to API Server "*.*.*.*:6443"
[discovery] Created cluster-info discovery client, requesting info from "https://*.*.*.*:6443"
I0304 09:13:14.967746 3176882 round_trippers.go:386] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "User-Agent: kubeadm/v1.11.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/a452946" -H "Accept: application/json, */*" 'https://*.*.*.*:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info'
I0304 09:13:14.974195 3176882 round_trippers.go:405] GET https://*.*.*.*:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info 401 Unauthorized in 6 milliseconds
I0304 09:13:14.974229 3176882 round_trippers.go:411] Response Headers:
I0304 09:13:14.974238 3176882 round_trippers.go:414]     Content-Type: application/json
I0304 09:13:14.974250 3176882 round_trippers.go:414]     Content-Length: 129
I0304 09:13:14.974260 3176882 round_trippers.go:414]     Date: Mon, 04 Mar 2019 16:13:14 GMT
I0304 09:13:14.974302 3176882 request.go:897] Response Body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401}
[discovery] Failed to request cluster info, will try again: [Unauthorized]
I0304 09:13:19.975419 3176882 round_trippers.go:386] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubeadm/v1.11.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/a452946" 'https://*.*.*.*:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info'
I0304 09:13:19.976262 3176882 round_trippers.go:405] GET https://*.*.*.*:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info 401 Unauthorized in 0 milliseconds
I0304 09:13:19.976288 3176882 round_trippers.go:411] Response Headers:
I0304 09:13:19.976300 3176882 round_trippers.go:414]     Content-Type: application/json
I0304 09:13:19.976313 3176882 round_trippers.go:414]     Content-Length: 129
I0304 09:13:19.976325 3176882 round_trippers.go:414]     Date: Mon, 04 Mar 2019 16:13:19 GMT
I0304 09:13:19.976366 3176882 request.go:897] Response Body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401}
[discovery] Failed to request cluster info, will try again: [Unauthorized]
```

Comment: Can you provide more output using -v9 debug option during `kubeadm join`?

Comment: @VKR - there's the verbose output.  Anything look wrong?  Thanks so much for looking!

Comment: The only thing that look wrong is your error :) And yes, you are right that this issue appears if  --anonymous-auth flag set to false, but not the true. Tried to reproduce couple of times with diff k8s versions but for me every time newly generated token works fine without problems...

Comment: @VKR - Thanks for taking the time.  I hate it when I'm the exception to the rule!  I'll see if a kube bug report gets me anywhere!  Again, thanks a ton.